# Linq exception on Provider.CreateQuery

Tags: c#, linq, system.linq.dynamic

Given this class:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public int SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

The following list:

```
var queryableData = new List<SomeClass>() {
    new SomeClass{SomeValue=1 },
    new SomeClass{SomeValue=2 },
    new SomeClass{SomeValue=3 },
    new SomeClass{SomeValue=4 },
    new SomeClass{SomeValue=5 },
    new SomeClass{SomeValue=6 },
    new SomeClass{SomeValue=7 },
}.AsQueryable();
```

And this code where i try to dinamically query the list (note that the string `query` could contain anything such as `Take`,`Select`,`OrderBy`, etc).

```
var externals = new Dictionary<string, object>();
externals.Add("SomeClass", queryableData);

string query = "SomeClass.Where(o => o.SomeValue >= 3)"; // or any query

// here i use the code from System.Linq.Dynamic
var expression = DynamicExpression.Parse(typeof(IQueryable<SomeClass>), query, new[] { externals });
// result will have five values
var result = queryableData.Provider.CreateQuery<SomeClass>(expression);

// here i use the code from System.Linq.Dynamic.Core
var expression2 = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(typeof(IQueryable<SomeClass>), query, new[] { externals });
// will throw exception here: Argument expression is not valid
var result2 = queryableData.Provider.CreateQuery<SomeClass>(expression2).ToDynamicArray();
```

I want to know what am i doing wrong that the `Provider.CreateQuery` is thowing the "Argument expression is not valid" exception?

Comment: Which of the two Provider.CreateQuery lines is throwing the exception, result or result2?

Comment: The last parameter to DynamicExpression.Parse / DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda are the substitution values, not the data source; in your example you have no substitution values. so you should omit this parameter.

Comment: @Edward, that's true, it was just some leftovers from a bigger code section simplified put it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference with `DynamicExpression.Parse` (hence the cause of the problem) is that the `DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda` method returns [LambdaExpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression?view=netframework-4.7.2) (basically `Expression<Func<TResult>>`) which is not a valid query expression.

But the [Body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression.body?view=netframework-4.7.2) of it is, so the simplest fix is to use

```
var result2 = queryableData.Provider.CreateQuery<SomeClass>(expression2.Body);
```

Alternatively you could use `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser` class directly:

```
var expression2 = new ExpressionParser(null, query, new[] { externals }, null)
    .Parse(typeof(IQueryable<SomeClass>));
var result2 = queryableData.Provider.CreateQuery<SomeClass>(expression2);
```